# Python Ctypes read char* returned from C++ dll

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I am discovering the world of ctypes because I am writing a DLL in C++ on Windows with a C wrapper to be able to use it on Python for example. I don't understand how it works with pointer on Python when I return for example a char * from my C++ function, how to get the data at the adress of the pointer ?

`myClass.h` file:

```
#include "myClassInc.h"
class __declspec(dllexport) myClass// __declspec to generate .lib file
{
public:
    // Attributes
    char * name;

    // Methods
    myClass();
    ~myClass();

    bool myMethod(string);
};
```

`myClassInc.h` (C wrapper) :

```
#ifdef MYCLASS
#  define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#  define EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

// Wrapper in C for others languages (LabVIEW, Python, C#, ...)
extern "C"
{
    EXPORT typedef struct myClass myClass; // make the class opaque to the wrapper
    EXPORT myClass* cCreateObject(void);
    EXPORT char* cMyMethod(myClass* pMyClass);
}
```

and `myClass.cpp` :

```
#include "myClass.h"

myClass::myClass() {}
myClass::~myClass() {}

bool myClass::myMethod(string filename_video)
{
    int iLength = filename_video.length();
    name = new char[iLength+1];
    strcpy(name, filename_video.c_str());
    return true;
}

myClass* cCreateObject(void)
{
    return new myClass();
}

char * cMyMethod(myClass* pMyClass)
{
    if (pMyClass->myMethod("hello world"))
        return pMyClass->name;
}
```

Finally `pythonScript.py` :

```
from ctypes import *

mydll = cdll.LoadLibrary("mydll.dll")
class mydllClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        mydll.cCreateObject.argtypes = [c_void_p]
        mydll.cCreateObject.restype = c_void_p

        mydll.cMyMethod.argtypes = [c_void_p]
        mydll.cMyMethod.restype = POINTER(c_char_p)

        self.obj = mydll.cCreateObject("")

    def myMethod(self):
        return mydll.cMyMethod(self.obj)

f = mydllClass() # Create object
a = f.myMethod() # WANT HERE TO READ "HELLO WORLD"
```

The result in a is `<__main__.LP_c_char_p object at 0x0000000002A4A4C8>`.

I don't find on the ctypes documentation how to read the data of a pointer like this. Can you help me please?

The same question will follow if I want to pass from Python a char * to myDll, how to do this (typically to give at the dll the path of a file to read from Python).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`c_char_p` is a `char*`.  `POINTER(c_char_p)` is a `char**`.  Fix your `.restype` and you should be good.  `ctypes` has a default behavior of converting a `c_char_p` to a Python byte string.

Also, `mydll.cCreateObject.argtypes = None` is correct for no arguments.  The existing definition states a `void*` is a required parameter.

Comment: If I take off `POINTER`, the program crashes (Python exactly) with `Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)`. Crash happens when I call `myMethod`. I tested returned an integer or boolean, and it is working. So the problem is with char* for now only.

Comment: @MathieuGauquelin The example provided doesn't compile as is (missing `#include <string>` for example).  After fixing errors and removing POINTER it worked for me.  You'll have to update the code to exactly as you have tested it.  Provide relative environment details as well.  I used Windows 10, VS2015, and Python 3.6 (all 64-bit).

Comment: It is working ;) Thank you ! I also succeed to send a string using `c_char_p("mystring".encode('utf-8'))`. Next step, get a double pointer of unsigned short :D

Comment: @Mathieu `b'hello'` is how to send a byte string. You don't need to wrap in c_char_p.